# How do I set a default static page for a ASP.Net Core Web API Project when start debug in VS2015?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using VS 2015 and have a ASP.Net Core 1.1 Web API Project.

If I start debug it will launch Edge with the following url: http://localhost:XXXXX/api/values

I have since long removed this controller but it still tries to find it.
I have read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files#serving-default-files) and made the appropriate changes to be able to show a static file.

In my wwwroot folder i have a Index.html file.
If i manually navigates to http://localhost:XXXXX the file is displayed.

My question is: How can I make VS2015 show my Index page when I start debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the option when right clicking the project and selecting properties. Then under the tab Debug, enabled Launch URL and entered the value.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `Properties/launchSettings.json` - it stores launch url which VS use.